# Close an Excel Workbook using Microsoft Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've exported two Excel workbooks from Microsoft Access queries, but the Excel Spreadsheets are left open. How do I close them? I've looked all over the internet for the answer and the code that I found says:

```
Dim objXLApp As Excel.Application
```

This does NOT work. I get the following error:

```
"Compile Error:
User-defined type not defined"
```

and "Excel.Application" is not an option from the drop-down.

Comment: what about the rest of your code? This single line doesn't tell everything about the possible problem. Try to add at the end of your sub this line: `Set objXLApp = Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need a reference to the excel application object model. "Microsoft Office Excel"

I'm not as familiar with access, however VBA is VBA... a reference is required.

try under Tools->References (from the VBA IDE)

And in the dialog there should be a Microsoft Office Excel, select it... then you should be able to do:

dim xlApp as Excel.Application

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to export?  Check out the [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214134%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method, or as I prefer (and am currently using) the [DoCmd.OutputTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx) method.  As long as you leave the *AutoStart* argument blank, it will remain false and not open the newly created file.  See below for an excerpt of code from my file:

`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "trndHistErrorRaterpt", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint`